# Can I make grub go back to the menu when I get the cryptomount passphrase wrong?

Tags: grub2, luks

I have GRUB 2 (EFI) booting my system, which is dual-boot between Debian 8.2 and Windows 10. The Debian system is on an encrypted partition, which is unlocked using cryptomount. This all works fine unless I type my passphrase wrong.

If I type my passphrase wrong when grub asks for it, I get a load of error spew (looks weird, but dealable with), and then "Press any key to continue". On pressing the any key, GRUB boots Windows 10. Is there any way to have it return to the GRUB menu instead?

I thought this might just be that the fallback option is set to Windows, but it's not actually set anywhere in my grub.cfg. I also can't find anything about this in the GRUB info files. So how can I customise this? Can I at least tell it to boot something else rather than windows when it fails to decrypt?

EDIT: worked out that, when this happens, GRUB reports that it failed to boot to the firmware or something, which then boots the next option on its list, which is windows. Question still stands though.

Comment: Is LUKS actually asks for password from initramfs which is waay too past beyond grub? Normal initramfs should just hard reset machine if too many invalid passwords were typed, and then usual grub menu reappears again. If _grub_ asks for password, then something is completely wrong with Linux today...

Comment: This is in a setup that is becoming more common (I think!) where one uses Grub to unlock the LUKS partition containing the kernel and initrd. This guide explains some of the idea behind it and a basic way to implement it: http://missinglink.xyz/grub2-bootloader/understanding-grub2-cryptomount/